# Windows 7 Taskbar: Capture thumbnails

Tags: .net, windows-7, thumbnails, taskbar, preview

Is it possible to capture the 'live' thumbnails from the Win7 taskbar? I want to display this preview (of another window) in my application, but how to extract those previews using .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

[MSDN Magazine explains how](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163435.aspx#S7).
You can also use the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack), which handles the interop for you.

Comment: The MSDN Magazine link no longer exists.  Can you update the answer to provide the actual details?

Answer (score 0):

There's a `System.Windows.Shell` namespace in .NET 4 that enables you capture thumbnails, etc. See [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140422222524/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usisvde/archive/2010/03/18/windows-7-taskbar-features-in-net-4.aspx)