# Thumbnail for running application on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, thumbnails

Is there any Win32 API that provides the thumbnail to a specific application running on Windows? I notice Window captures these thumbnails when we hover the mouse over the taskbar but is this exposed to developers?

[image]

> I'm coding in C++ and expect the API in C++.

Comment: Note that *none* of the Win32 API is straight C++, it's either C or COM interfaces.

Comment: @MarkRansom GDI+ is sort of c++ only, the c interface is deprecated and was never fully supported.

Comment: @Anders: GDI+ does have a C interface. The C interface was never deprecated. It's just cumbersome to work with. Just like working with COM in C is cumbersome. Yet fully supported. Do you have a reference for the deprecation?

Comment: @IInspectable "It is recommended that you do not directly call the functions in the flat API" "Microsoft Product Support Services will not provide support for code that calls the flat API directly" but I could not find the specific page with some other details I remember from back in the day.

Comment: @Anders: That doesn't read like it's deprecated, though. It's not recommended to use GDI+' C interface for the same reason it's not recommended to use COM from C: Because it's tedious, error-prone, and better alternatives exist.

Answer (score 0):

These "thumbnails" are parts of Windows itself and cannot be modified.

Comment: Can we have access to it without modification?

Comment: No.  And the thumbnails may be generated dynamically by the apps themselves in response to [`WM_DWMSENDICONICLIVEPREVIEWBITMAP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd938874.aspx) and [`WM_DWMSENDICONICTHUMBNAIL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd938875.aspx) messages sent by the Desktop Window Manager when it interacts with the Taskbar.  In short, the generation of thumbnails is private to Windows and not publically accessible.

Comment: [According to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009064/), it is possible (in .NET), but the answers are stale and the particular details have been lost to time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It sounds we have access to its bitmap after its generation.

Comment: @hackjutsu: there is no API to retrieve the actual bitmaps, and the DWM messages I mentioned simply ask windows to generate bitmaps but they don't receive the actual bitmaps in reply. The apps that process those messages must call [`DwmSetIconicLivePreviewBitmap()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389410.aspx)/[`DwmSetIconicThumbnail()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389411.aspx) to pass the bitmaps to DWM. So, unless you want to hook those APIs directly, you can't intercept the bitmaps.

Comment: @hackjutsu: You might try using [`DwmRegisterThumbnail()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969521.aspx), though.  See [DWM Thumbnail Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969541.aspx), but due note the following: "*DWM thumbnails do not enable developers to create applications like the Windows Vista Flip3D (WINKEY-TAB) feature. **Thumbnails are rendered directly to the destination window in 2-D**.*"